# Pointer to pointer doesn't store all values — only the last one

Tags: c

The problem is when I try to print the values of 
`(*names)[*number]`, I get only the last one stored.

I'll explain what I mean with an example — what I want is this:

```
 (*names)[0] = "john"
 (*names)[1] = "bill"
 (*names)[2] = "nick"
```

and what I get when I print the values of `(*names)[*number]` is this:

```
 (*names)[0] = "nick"
 (*names)[1] = "nick"
 (*names)[2] = "nick"
```

Here is the code:

```
int GetFiles(char **dir,char ***names,int *number)
{
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *fd;
    int i;

    if ((fd = opendir(*dir)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open directory %s!\n",*dir);
        return 0;
    }
    *number = 0;

    //*names = (char**)malloc(((*number)+1) * sizeof(char*));

    *names = (char**)malloc(17*sizeof(char*));

    while ((dp = readdir(fd)) != NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(dp->d_name, ".."))
        {
            continue;
        }

        (*names)[*number] = dp->d_name;

        (*number)++;

        //*names = (char**)realloc(*names,((*number)+1) * sizeof(char*));
    }

    closedir(fd);

    for(i=0;i<*number;i++)
    {
        printf("--%s\n",(*names)[i]);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: try `(*names)[*number] = dp->d_name;` --> `(*names)[*number] = strdup(dp->d_name);`

Comment: Thank you BLUEPIXY , it worked.Could you give me an explanation why my code failed?

Comment: `dp->d_name` is assumed to be the address of the same memory chunk. So make a copy. It need to `free` later.

Comment: `readdir` returns a pointer to the same structure every time, just filled in with different information. Your original code only saves the address of `d_name`, which doesn't change, so every entry in your array contains the same pointer. The name you see is the last name `readdir` returned.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!Everything is clear now.

Comment: Note that by the time your original code is printing, you are referencing deallocated memory (because you did `closedir()`).  If you're using `strdup()`, don't forget to free the duplicated strings.